# Firebase cannot be linked to BigQuery "An error occurred while trying to link. Please try again."

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have several firebase apps and all of them are linked to bigquery - with 0 effort but one.

This one, somehow says

> An error occurred while trying to link. Please try again.

when trying to link the big query...

I can see the project in bigquery already but still not linked yet ... anyone happened to experience the same?

If any more info is needed, I can provide.. however dunno what to specifically provide for this super simple two-step process :( especially since other projects linked just fine in, literally, two clicks

is there probably any way to unlink it from bigquery so I can try to link it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I contacted the FB support ... and it turned out there was an app pending deletion in this particular project... so going to "Project Settings" and under the general tab - scrolling down.. there is a card "Your apps" ... I could see the one pending .. after deleting it, it worked flawlessly... I suggested to FB Support that a better more explanatory error message would be nice ... so just in case anyone happens to experience this ... worth checking :)